# no tests were executed for sbt integration test in system folder

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I want to run `sbt system:test` to run the integration tests in `system` folder. Here's the `build.sbt` changes, but it the console log still says `No tests were executed`. any ideas why? thanks!!

```
 lazy val `myproj` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).configs(SystemTest).settings(
   inConfig(SystemTest)(Defaults.testSettings),
   // other settings here
 )
 lazy val SystemTest = config("system") extend Test describedAs "System tests"
```

Comment: If you start `sbt` and then run `inspect system:test`, what do you see?

Comment: When I ran `sbt inspect system:test` I got the following errors:`[error] inspect usage:
[error]   inspect [tree|uses|definitions|actual] <key>   Prints the value for 'key', the defining scope, delegates, related definitions, and dependencies.
[error] 
[error] inspect
[error]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .configs(SystemTest)
  .settings( inConfig(SystemTest)(Defaults.testSettings) : _*)

lazy val SystemTest = config("system") extend(Test)

scalaSource in SystemTest := baseDirectory.value / "/system"
```

The last line is to give the path of the folder where yours test cases are.

You can see this [blog](https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/04/26/integration-test-configuration-in-play-framework/) as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Play/SBT offer You integration tests "out of the box" with command `sbt it:test` and below configuration:

`lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(
    Defaults.itSettings,
  )`